# How to pass parameter in url and call api with it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using ReactJS and I have filters in post page. What I want is that when I click on filters it should pass parameters in URL and call the API on the basis of it.
Can anyone suggest an example some for it?.

```
E.g. history.push ({
pathname:'/users',
search:'?filter1=value_filter1'
})
```

in above code how to add multiple values and remove values

Comment: Could you add some code or a sandbox of what you have up until now?

Comment: no i dont know how to do it so i dont have any code

Comment: check the question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand,you would like to update your url by adding query parametres based on filters.
The simplest way to add query params is through the `push` method of `hasHistory` by passing an object as parametre .
E.g.
`history.push ({
pathname:'/users',
search:'?filter1=value_filter1'
})`

It also possible to pass an object into the search key with params

For more information about how it works,you can go into the following links : [Make it easier to add query parameters](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1100) or this youtube video [Query Strings with React Router](https://youtu.be/37-LglMzt8w)

Comment: how i adding and removing values from it ?

Comment: Okay,i've juste updated my answer by providing additionnal link to help reach your goal

Comment: video is not helping it only show how to get query values not add